# How do I view my site with full formatting without having to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was working on a small project using html, css and javascript. When I viewed the page using VS code's live server the page worked fine but when I uploaded the project to github and hosted it on github pages the site comes out unformatted. I have to refresh the page once to load the formatting. I do not understand what the issue is but I beleive it has something to do with the loading of the javascript. Can you tell me how to resolve this issue

Site on github pages:
https://abhimanyu-dev.github.io/Calculator/

Github repository link:
https://github.com/Abhimanyu-dev/Calculator

Comment: can't reproduce - works fine on load - at least, in Firefox, but you're probably using Chrome or EdgeChrome while do this sort of stuff randomly - chrome does complain about `permissions-policy: interest-cohort=()`

Comment: nowhere is `interest-cohort` documented as anything to do wiht `permissions-policy` header - though I can't see this stopping chrome from only sometimes loading correctly if it doesn't understand the value in that header ...

Comment: Load all your settings like this document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('load settings here');
});

Comment: Only suggestion I'd make is to put the script tag at the bottom of the body (i.e. just before `</body>`) .... thought `defer` would have a similar effect, but give it a try